# CodeceptJS: Launch a page with dynamic query string

Tags: codeceptjs

I have a page which needs to be launched with a query string that's generated after a sendPostRequest call.

```js
async goToPage(){
    const pageId= await I.sendPostRequest(url);
    I.amOnPage(/details?id=${pageId});
}
```

I am calling this method in my step file.
Issue that am facing is, page that's generated in report is blank, even if I call a static page it's blank. But if I remove the async, await then I can see the page in report generated.
Basically when I call a page after a await, the page is not redirected even though I can see pageId query string has the value returned after the post call.
Please assist on the same.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the backticks.
`` I.amOnPage(`/details?id=${pageId}`); ``